# Error while validation password using submission throttling

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a login page where I am validating Email and Password entered by user using concept of submission throttling from the database.
The error say: undefined index:'txtMail' at validate page.I have an alert box after readyState and status property in login page to know what result I am getting from the server side.

> ```
> <html>
>
> <head>
>     <title>LOGIN FORM</title>
>     <meta charset="UTF-8">
>     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
>
>     <script>
>         function check()
>         {
>             var name = document.getElementById('txtMail').value;
>             var pass = document.getElementById('txtPass').value;
>             var msg="";
>
>             if(name == "" || pass == "")
>             {
>                 if(name == "")
>                 {
>                     msg="Please Enter Email ID";
>                     document.getElementById('errMail').innerHTML=msg;
>                 }
>
>                 else
>                     if(pass == "")
>                 {
>                     msg="Please Enter Password";
>                     document.getElementById('errPass').innerHTML=msg;
>                 }
>                 else
>                     {
>                         msg="";
>                        document.getElementById('errMail').innerHTML=msg;
>                        document.getElementById('errPass').innerHTML=msg;
>                     }
>             }
>             else
>                 if(name == "" && pass == "")
>                 {
>                     msg="Please Enter All The Details";
>                     alert($msg);
>                 }
>                 else
>                     {
>                         alert("Login Succcessful");
>                     }
>
>         }
>         function validate(element)
>         {                
>             var xmlhttp;
>              //var m= document.getElementById('txtMail').value;
>             // var p=document.getElementById('txtPass').value;
>             if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
>             {
>                 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
>             }
>             else
>             {
>                 xmlhttp=new Activexobject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
>             }
>             var myField=element;
>             xmlhttp.open('GET','validate.php?'+myField.id+"="+myField.value,true);
>             xmlhttp.send();
>             xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
>             {
>                 if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
>                 {
>                     //alert(""+m);
>                    // alert(""+p);
>                     var response=xmlhttp.responseText.split("||");
>                     alert(""+response);
>                 }
>                 var divname="err"+myField.id.substring(3);
>                 var mydiv=document.getElementById(divname);
>                 if(!eval(response[0]))
>                 {
>                     mydiv.innerHTML=response[1];
>                     myField.valid=false;
>                 }
>                 else
>                 {
>                     myField.valid=true;
>                     mydiv.innerHTML="";
>
>                 }
>                 var btn=document.getElementById("LoginBtn");
>                 btn.disabled=!isValidForm();
>             }
>         };
>         function isValidForm()
>         {
>             var f1=document.getElementById("txtMail");
>             var f2=document.getElementById("txtPass");
>             return(f1.valid && f2.valid);
>         };      
>         function redirection()
>         {
>             window.location="signup.html";
>         }
>     </script>
>     <meta charset="utf-8">
>     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
>     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
>     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
>     <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
> </head>
> <body>
>     <center>          
>             <br><br>
>             <table>
>                 <tr>
>                     <td>Email ID: </td>
>                     <td><input type=text id="txtMail" name="txtMail" onchange="validate(this)" valid=false> </td>
>                     <td><div id="errMail"/></td>
>                 </tr>
>                 <tr><td><br></td><td/></tr>
>                 <tr>
>                     <td>Password: </td>
>                     <td><input type=password id="txtPass" name="txtPass" onchange="validate(this)" valid=false></td>
>                     <td><div id="errPass"/></td>
>                 </tr>
>             </table>
>             <br>
>             <div class="container">
>                 <input type="submit" onclick='check()' id="LoginBtn" disabled="true" value="Login"/>
>                 <button type="button" class='btn btn-success'  onclick="redirection()">Sign up </button>
>
>             </div>
>
>             <br>
>             <br>
>             <br>
>             <br>
>
>             <center><font color="red">© 2007-2015 sharemybooks.in</font> </center>
>     </center>
>
> </body>
>
> </html>
> ```

validate php page is as follows:

> ```
> <?php include 'connection.php'; $v = false; $m = "An Unknown Error Occured"; if(isset($_GET["txtMail"])) {
> $emailId=$_GET['txtMail'];
> $checkdata="SELECT Email_Id FROM Customer WHERE Email_Id='$emailId'";
> $query=mysql_query($checkdata);
>
> if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0)
> {
>     $v=true;
>     $m="";
> }
> else
> {
>     $v=false;
>     $m="Email Does not Exists";
> } } if(isset($_GET["txtPass"])) {
> //if(isset ($_GET["txtMail"]))
> //{
>     $sql="SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Email_Id = '".$_GET['txtMail']."' AND Password = '".$_GET['txtPass']."'";
>     $query=mysql_query($sql);
>
>     if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0)
>     {
>         $v=true;
>         $m="succ";
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         $v=false;
>         $m="Invalid Password";
>     }
> //} } echo $v."||".$m;
> ?>
> ```

Comment: The variable is not set, make sure you have spelt it all correct and are checking that the variable `isset`.

Comment: `if(!eval(response[0]))` is bad.

Comment: You are not sending up both textMail and textPassword to your PHP page. I am not sure how you are reading both of them from the querystring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 

include 'connection.php';

$sql="SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Email_Id = '".$_GET['txtMail']."' AND   Password = '".$_GET['txtPass']."'";

$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

if(!empty($row['Email_id']) AND !empty($row['password']))
{
header("Location: home.php");
}
else
{
$message = "Incorrect USERNAME or PASSWORD";
}
}
```

Comment: same problem exists. @B.Nadesh kumar

Answer (score 0):

You should be posting the request not using `GET` as you are passing the variable the PHP page.

Change,

```
xmlhttp.open('GET','validate.php?'+myField.id+"="+myField.value,true);
```

To,

```
xmlhttp.open('POST','validate.php?'+myField.id+"="+myField.value, true);
```

Comment: UM, querystring values are a GET, where are the POST variables?

Comment: I changed it to POST now it prints the default value of variable msg.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP code is expecting that you are sending up two things

```
.$_GET['txtMail']."' AND Password = '".$_GET['txtPass']."'"; 
       ^^^^^^^^^                             ^^^^^^^^^
```

And the JavaScript code is sending up one

```
xmlhttp.open('GET','validate.php?'+myField.id+"="+myField.value,true);
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^
```

You are also using `eval` which is a bad idea.

Comment: Ok. What is other option ?Actually I have learnt this concept and it uses eval function. @epascarello

Comment: What are you trying to do with eval? Modern development uses JSON which uses JSON.parse(). You are just returning a string it appears so you can just check for the string.